# Syntax for setting/updating register fields in Map CRDT on server

Tags: erlang, riak, crdt

What is the syntax for setting `lwwreg` register values in `CRDT Map` on server side in Riak? I tried a code like below which doesn't seem to be valid:

```
%% Obj is a map object to which we want to add/set a register "uname" with value
%% "ahmed"
riak_kv_crdt:update(Obj,<<"testing">>,{crdt_op,riak_dt_map,
{update,[{assign,<<"uname">>,<<"ahmed">>}]},undefined})
```

I get an error about the operation being invalid - I looked around in source code for [`riak_dt_map.erl`](https://github.com/basho/riak_dt/blob/develop/src/riak_dt_map.erl) but still can't figure out correct syntax:

```
> riak_kv_crdt:update(Obj,<<"testing">>,{crdt_op,riak_dt_map,{update,
  [{assign,<<"uname">>,<<"ahmed">>}]},undefined}).

** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    riak_dt_map:apply_ops([{assign,<<"uname">>,<<"ahmed">>}],
                                          {<<"testing">>,1},
                                          {[{<<"testing">>,1}],
                    .....
```

Will appreciate pointers on correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The correct syntax is below - the key must be accompanied by the type of the field which is `riak_dt_lwwreg` in this case, and `assign` operation must be specified for register value - so, the syntax becomes:

```
riak_kv_crdt:update(Obj,<<"testing">>,{crdt_op,riak_dt_map,{update,
[{update,{<<"uname">>,riak_dt_lwwreg},{assign,<<"ahmed">>}}]},undefined})
```

Comment: But here you are using an _internal_ riak api, not the one exposed over HTTP or PB. It may change. Be careful!